# How to rotate+scale PDF pages around the center with pypdf?

Tags: python, pdf, rotation, pypdf

I would like to rotate PDF pages around the center (other than just multiples of 90°) in a PDF document and optionally scale them to fit into the original page.

Here on StackOverflow, I found a few similar questions, however, mostly about the outdated PyPDF2.
And in the [latest pypdf documentation](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), I could not find (or overlooked) a recipe to rotate pages around the center, e.g. for slightly tilted scanned documents, which require rotation of a few degrees.

I know that there is the `Transformation Class`, but the standard rotation is around the lower left corner and documentation is not explaining in detail what the matrix elements actually are.

How to rotate a PDF page around the center and optionally scale it that it fits into the original page?

Comment: You can translate so that (0,0) is the center. Then rotate. Then translate back.

Comment: @MartinThoma thank you for your comment. Oops, it looks like I made it more complicated than it is with the transformation matrix. But for the proper scaling I still need some trigonometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to figure out how to rotate a page around the center and scale it to fit the original page. Although, it just requires [a matrix with the correct elements at the right place](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2093314/720419) and some trigonometric functions, it was not too obvious for me.
Hence, I post the script I ended up with for my own memories and maybe it is helpful to others not having to re-invent the wheel.

After all, you can also achieve it somehow via a combination of `rotate()`, `translate()`, and `scale()`.

If anybody has ideas to simplify or improve the following script, please let me know.

**Script:**

```
### rotate around center (and optional scale) pdf pages
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter, Transformation
from math import sin, cos, atan, sqrt, radians, pi

pdf_input  = PdfReader("Test.pdf")
pdf_output = PdfWriter()

rotation_angle = 7.3    # in degrees
shrink_page    = True

for page in pdf_input.pages:
    x0 = (page.mediabox.right - page.mediabox.left)/2
    y0 = (page.mediabox.top   - page.mediabox.bottom)/2
    a  = radians(rotation_angle)
    a0 = atan(max(x0,y0)/min(x0,y0))
    s0 = min(x0,y0)/cos(a0 - abs((a-pi/2)%pi - pi/2))/sqrt(x0**2 + y0**2) if shrink_page else 1
    rotate_center = Transformation((
        s0*cos(a), s0*sin(a), -s0*sin(a), s0*cos(a), 
        s0*(-x0*cos(a)+y0*sin(a))+x0, s0*(-x0*sin(a)-y0*cos(a))+y0))
    pdf_output.add_page(page).add_transformation(rotate_center)

pdf_output.write("Test_out.pdf")
### end of script
```

Alternatively, as @MartinThoma commented, instead of using the transformation matrix (or tuple) use `translate()`, `rotate()` and again `translate()` and optionally `scale()`, but in the right order with the proper numbers. This means, replace the line `rotate_center = ...` with the following:

```
rotate_center = Transformation().translate(tx=-x0,ty=-y0).scale(sx=s0,sy=s0).rotate(rotation_angle).translate(tx=x0,ty=y0)
```

**Result:** (screenshot from `Test_out.pdf`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for simpler alternatives or a python one line shell command.

Many Graphics Editors can rotate Pages by any given amount by using overlay method.
[image]

The advantage with Python coding is, it is easily adaptable for any rotation.

However, once you determine your desired page width (here 650 points) then manually or via shell system command line methods from python. This is easily programmed in one line, as many PDF libraries will overlay multiple pages on a blank canvas (after that prior calculation).

Here using [pdfcpu (one 9.86 MB exe)](https://github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu) but many others can do similar.

```
pdfcpu stamp add -mode pdf -- "PDF-Wikipedia.pdf:1" "rot:7.3, scale:1.0 rel" NewDocument.pdf rotated.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, `pdfcpu` seems to be a powerful tool. Actually, rotating around the center was just one part of my intended tool, which allows merging, extracting, rotating from multiple files into one file. I'm sure `pdfcpu` can do that as well, but my focus was on a GUI for users who are scared by the command line and prefer drag&drop. Furthermore, I was annoyed by the many free-PDF tools which are possibly ad-, spy- or mal-ware and in the end dont't have the functions I want. Maybe there is already a GUI-interface for `pdfcpu`?!